# Creating a wrapper directive for Bootstrap-UI's uib-datepicker-popup

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a wrapper AngularJS directive for Bootstrap-UI's uib-datepicker-popup so I don't have to recreate a bunch of boilerplate each time I need to select a date. [I've been working off an example I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562213/how-to-create-an-angularjs-wrapper-directive-for-a-ui-bootstrap-datepicker) which was written for an earlier version of Angular, and am running into some oddities getting this working.

I've gotten the directive to a point where it displays a popup, however the two-way data binding seems to be broken; the date value in the field's model doesn't propagate into the directive, and when you click on the popup and select a date, it doesn't propagate back out. Does anyone have any ideas on what's going on here?

[I've created a Plunker demonstrating the issue here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/swVZlQ2SYJMRvU9xx74P?p=preview)

Directive code:

```
app.directive('myDatepicker', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
          model: "=",
          myid: "@"
      },
      templateUrl: 'datepicker.html',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element) {
          scope.popupOpen = false;
          scope.openPopup = function($event) {
              $event.preventDefault();
              $event.stopPropagation();
              scope.popupOpen = true;
          };

          scope.open = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            scope.opened = true;
          };

      }
  };
});
```

Template code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{myid}}" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="model" is-open="opened" ng-required="true"  />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using ng-model in the directive code, but you're looking for model in the directive template.

```
<my-datepicker ng-model="selected" myid="someid"></my-datepicker>
```

And here you are looking for an attribute called model:

```
app.directive('myDatepicker', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
          //this line should be ngModel
          model: "=",
          myid: "@"
      },
```

Here's a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/s5CT4xGqXtUxgCH8vw8q?p=preview

In general, I try to avoid using names like "model" and "ng-model" on custom directives, as built-in angular attributes should be distinguished from custom attributes.

Comment: How would you pass the datepicker-options to the directive ?